# Prove that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_jb_j\right)^2 \le \left(\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2/j\right)$

Tags: inequality, summation

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_jb_j\right)^2 \le \left(\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2/j\right)$$

For all real numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$.

I tried applying the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality), tried a different summation order.. didn't get very far. It's from "[Linear Algebra Done Right](http://books.google.com/books?id=ovIYVIlithQC&pg=PA122)" by Sheldon Axler.

Also I have other questions from this exercise section, I wonder if I should ask them separately or put them in the same thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try using $a_j\sqrt{j}$ and $b_j/\sqrt{j}$.

Comment: Even though it is from a book about linear algebra, I do not think that ([tag:linear-algebra]) is a good tag for this.

Comment: I agree, it's just that I couldn't come up with a better one as I was about to post. :) 
Now I know of a new tag, haha!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just Cauchy-Schwarz on : $x_j^2:=ja_j^2$ and $y_j^2:=b_j^2/j$

Comment: I feel like a retard. This was really obvious and I somehow managed to miss it. Thanks.

Comment: Happens (: . You're welcome

Comment: Rather, $x_j := \sqrt{j}a_j$ and $y_j := b_j/\sqrt{j}$, no?

Comment: yes. I was to lazy because the answer was really obvious. Will edit.

Comment: @AdarHefer Relax, if Grothendieck thought that [57 is a prime](https://mfluch.wordpress.com/2007/12/26/57-the-grothendieck-prime/), then we, mere mortals, are free to slip on little things like that.